# removing <br> from image hover over caption in php

Tags: php

I am working on showing images via a database for a project with slimbox formatting, and am having issues with the mouse-over/hover-over caption. In the code I have

```
echo '<a href="images/' . $filename . '" rel="lightbox-set1"  
title="' . $description.'<br>'."licence: ". $Licence. $Owner.'">';
echo '<img src="images-thumb/' . $filename . '" />';
echo '</a>';
```

and the mouse over caption for the image on screen shows:

```html
The Lagoon in wellington<br>licence:free for all
```

I want to know if there is a way to remove the `<br>` from the caption displayed, without actually removing it, (`<br>`), from the code itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `<br>` tag to a PHP line break `PHP_EOL`:

```
title="' . $description . PHP_EOL . 'licence: ' . $Licence . $Owner . '">';
```

Answer (score 0):

This will insert a carriage return inside your title.

```
echo '<a href="images/' . $filename . '" rel="lightbox-set1"  
title="' . $description.'&&#35;13;'."licence: ". $Licence. $Owner.'">';
echo '<img src="images-thumb/' . $filename . '" />';
echo '</a>';
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to have a new line when the user hovers to your image try this one

```
echo '<a href="images/' . $filename . '" rel="lightbox-set1"  
title="' . $description.' &#013; '."licence: ". $Licence. $Owner.'">';
```